# AS400 iseries with azure office365

Tags: ibm-midrange

I switched recently to a company after using SAP for years and I'm completely lost after having found that they are using AS400 still!.
I never used it before and I have three questions:

1. Is the ibm iaccess navigator good to use the console or there are other consoles specially for windows and macos?
2. As we use office365 and azure is there a way to get data exported and visualize it on some other cool saas service? Specially to have charts or any else?
3. Is there a settings panel or admin access or list of commands? Or even a good book to buy to understand commands?

Comment: Are they actually running an AS/400?  Or are they running IBM i v7.3 on POWER9?  And FYI, IBM i is one of the preferred platforms for SAP.

Comment: @chares thank you for your answer, we run IBM i on a power 8 tower server.

Answer (score 1):

iSeries Navigator has been superseded... may work, but if you're running Windows 10 it is not supported.

There's a new Java based client, [Access Client Solutions (ACS)](https://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/solutions.html) that gets you 5250 emulation and some DB stuff.

However, most the admin stuff has been moved to [IBM Navigator for i](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzat10/rzatgdirectoroverview.htm) which is a web based server application.  You should be able to access it via http://myibmi:2001

Documentation for the IBM i is here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzahg/ic-homepage.htm

**EDIT**
As far as analytics or visualizing the data.  You can use SQL to access data on Db2 for i just like any other RDBMS.  ODBC, ADO, .NET, and JDBC drivers are available.  ACS includes a "Run SQL Scripts" component or you can use any number of open source tools.

Analytics are not a function of the platform, they are a function of the software package you're using.  If you were running SAP on i, you've have the same SAP provided analytics you're used to.  If your package doesn't have any, then you can build some in whatever you'd want.

IBM Watson Analytics now has a built in connector for Db2 for i.
https://www.itjungle.com/2017/06/14/new-data-connection-ibm-watson-analytics/

Comment: thank you Charles, very useful informations to begin, but there is an analytics like Google Analytics app or something like that to visualize data in ibm i? Is very frustating to navigating the console without the gui, searching on web I found IBM Cognos but I don't know if it is right and free.

Comment: @Marcos see edit